# Sealant/joining compound for kitchen laminate worktop installation

Tags: wood, kitchens, sealing, kitchen-counters, laminate

What is the recommended sealant and joining product for use with laminate kitchen worktops? I have a butt joint within 10cm of the kitchen sink, and water has penetrated the joint and expanded the chipboard inside the worktop, resulting in a bulge.

The worktops were joined and sealed with Unika ColorFill, which claims to be a waterproof worktop sealant. However, in practice I found it to shrink and open up small cracks within weeks, which lead to the water ingress.

The only option is to replace the kitchen worktops, but I don't want to use Colorfill again, as is recommended by the supplier of the worktops. Is there an alternative product that can be used? I have read waterproof/exterior PVA could be an option?

My previous worktop was also laminate and lasted fine until it was eventually replaced after 15 years. I do not know what product was used to seal and join it, but would like to know what is common practice amongst professionals so I can avoid doing it wrong again.

Comment: Can you re-position the join further away from the sink? 10cm is in the "permanent splash" area...  I have joined these with an aluminum or stainless joiner that works well - done 15 years in my parents kitchen...

Comment: @SolarMike unfortunately the position of the joint is necessary, the two lengths of worktop are in a right angle formation and the small size of the kitchen prevents any other configuration. I will look into a metal joining strip, thanks